# INTERSECTing tables with multiple return values

Tags: sql, oracle

May i ask how do i check for similar group of result for this SQL question.

```
===========
EMPLOYEE
===========
ID | Name |
===========
 1 | EMP1 |
 2 | EMP2 |

==================
HASSKILL
==================
EMPID | SkillID  |
  1   | 001      |
  1   | 002      |
  1   | 003      |
  2   | 003      |
  2   | 004      |
  2   | 005      |

JOB
===================
JobID | NEEDSKILL |
===================
  1   | 002       |
  1   | 003       |
```

I can get the skill needed by the job with the following command:

```
SELECT NEEDSKILL FROM JOB WHERE JobID = 1;
```

How do i "loop" through the employee and display employee which has the skills needed for job 1 without pl/sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select empid from HASSKILL, JOB
where jobid = 1 and skillid = needskill
group by empid
having count(0) = (select count(0) from JOB where jobid = 1)
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for replying, can you explain you code for me as i cant really understand it. Thanks.

Comment: It counts the number of skills for each employee and checks this number to be equal to number of skills required.

Comment: wouldn't this be wrong if there is another job which has the same number skill required but a different skill id?

Comment: we count only skills among required for jobid=1

Comment: Having two aggregates seems to be a very inefficient way of doing it. Also you are not actually displaying the Employee but rather his ID.

Comment: hi magnus, i can select * from employee where id in (his solution), but  if i understand correctly his solution only compare with the number of skills which will be wrong if 2 jobs has the same number of skill but diff skill set is needed.